# Looking for a WordPress plugin to use as an example/starting point

Tags: php, wordpress, open-source

I would like to write a WordPress plugin that provides the ability to maintain database of potentially detailed entries, and then a filterable view of those entries.  Specifically I would like to maintain a player roster, with a set of specific fields for each player.  It would include mostly simple fields, though I foresee needing to upload and reference photos as well.

I assume the hard part of this would be the administration page, providing your basic CRUD functionality for the table, then potentially the filterable view.  I also assume that this is specific enough that there is not a plugin that fits my needs out of the box.  Attempts to find one have come up empty, with one [defunct](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/leaguemanager/) effort and one that is much more [complex](http://www.wp-swimteam.org/) than I'd like to start with.

So, can anyone point me at a good open source example of a plugin that would get me started, specifically something that creates custom table(s) and provides a CRUD like administration page for maintaining the tables.  I'm sure I could write stand alone php scripts to do this, but I'd like to write it in the context of WP, and consider releasing it back on the community.

Answer (score 2):

For a CRUD application in admin, I would like to recommend WP MVC. WP MVC is an MVC framework for WordPress, distributed as a plugin. It's not an out-of-the-box solution, but when mastered, it helps you to write quickly such applications. Latest stable version (1.2) allows you to integrate your custom models(stored in dedicated tables) with WordPress data (Posts,PostsMeta, Users/UsersMeta and Comments/CommentsMeta).

Comment: There are several people working on versions of this code (myself included). If you hit any problems or are interested in how to get wp-mvc to do stuff, ask on the wordpress support forum (http://wordpress.org/tags/wp-mvc) and do check out the various forks available in github (https://github.com/tombenner/wp-mvc/network)